# In WPF, how to call an owner window method from child window inside BackgroundWorker without instantiation?

Tags: c#, wpf, backgroundworker

In the **MainWindow**, I could call **MyMethod** from **DoWork** event easily, and that works fine since **MyMethod** doesn't have access to any UI control.

My question is how to call the same method (MyMethod) in the **child** window without **instantiation** a new object, where the following statement works correctly **outside** the BackgroundWorker

```
((MainWindow)this.Owner).MyMethod();
```

But **inside** the BackgroundWorker (in the child Window) this statement throws an Exception, although it doesn't have any access to UI and it could be called inside the BackgroundWoerker in the MainWindow.

Any attempt to help me will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the exception? Also, how is the child window initialized? You might have to manually set its owner to the parent class upon instantiation.

Comment: MainWindow was created on the main thread.  Cannot access it from a backgoundworker.

Comment: @Mahmoud - MainWindow is a DependencyObject and they have constraint that they can be accessed from same thread on which it was created. Hence an exception. Put it on corresponding dispatcher and it will work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When calling RunWorkerAsync(), consider using the overload that takes an object. If you are calling RunWorkerAsync() from the UI thread of the child window, you could instead call

```
bw.RunWorkerAsync(this.Owner);
```

You can then pull that object out of the DoWork event args and invoke your method on that object.

```
((MainWindow)e.Argument).MyMethod();
```

Comment: Great answer. This is what I was looking for. Thank you. For others, I used RunWorkerAsync(this.Owner);

Comment: Oh wow, yeah, I messed up those method calls. Should have been RunWorkerAsync() as you said, not DoWork().

Answer (score 0):

You need to invoke the call on the Dispatcher UI thread:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { MyMethod() });
```